# Using iTextSharp with knockout JavaScript or other MVC / MVVM framework?

Tags: c#, pdf, knockout.js, itext

Ok, since I did find out that I can use iTextSharp to generate a PDF, I went that route.

I've got it to where it will save HTML with basic formatting to a PDF. That's not the problem.

What I'm needing to do now is take markup with *knockout* in it, and use the *resultant* HTML (i.e. the DOM) as my string to pass into the method that creates the PDF.

So, for instance, I have a table that's generated with knockout. I need to pass the DOM that was generated by knockout, as a string, into my C# controller, so that I can build the PDF.

Basically, if you look at what's generated here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

And if you read through Example 2 (it generates three bullet points), it illustrates the generation I'm talking about. In my case, I would want to take the generated bullet points and pass them into my controller -- HTML and all -- as a string, so that I can save them.

Any thoughts? I'm not even sure where to *begin* here, honestly.

Comment: In `self.addPerson`: [1] Get `outerHTML` of `ul` (don't know `knockout.js`, but easy with jQuery); [2] send Ajax request to controller. In controller: [1] parse HTML string with `XMLWorkerHelper`; [2] return `ActionResult` with PDF stream.

Comment: Thanks @kuujinbo. I'll give that a shot and let you know how it turns out. Will that capture any inline styles as well?

Comment: It should capture at least some of them. But keep your expectations in check. And if you're using `Bootstrap` or similar, the output will look **very** different from what's rendered in the browser. `iText[Sharp]`'s CSS parser is **very** simple - [here's a list of supported styles](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm). I'll throw a quick and dirty sample of my earlier comment up as an answer a little later today. :)

Answer (score 0):

The question applies to *any* JavaScript Framework that does `MVC` or `MVVM`. Mentioned above:

> I need to pass the DOM that was generated by knockout, as a string,
>   into my C# controller, so that I can build the PDF.

So am going to go with a simple working example to get this done in ASP.NET MVC. Never used `knockout.js` before, so going to get the `DOM` element and send `Ajax` request with `jQuery`.

The view, based on the example you referenced above: **1.** Gets `outerHTML` of `ul`; **2.** sends an `Ajax` request to the controller:

```
<h4>People</h4>
<ul id='wanted' data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
<button data-bind="click: getPdf">Get PDF</button>

@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/libs/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ajax/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ajax/jquery.binarytransport.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ajax/jquery-binary.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.getPdf = function (data, event) {
            $(this).downloadFile(
                '@Url.Action("Index", "DomToPdf")',
                { xHtml: $('#wanted').prop('outerHTML') }
            );
        }

        self.people = ko.observableArray([
            { name: 'Bert' },
            { name: 'Charles' },
            { name: 'Denise' }
        ]);
        self.addPerson = function () {
            self.people.push({ name: "New at " + new Date() });
        };
        self.removePerson = function () {
            self.people.remove(this);
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
}
```

Notes:

1. [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) isn't technically required, but saves a great deal of time not having to deal with different browser implementations. Reference [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).
2. [BinaryTransport](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport) **is** required if using `jQuery` - sadly the framework [doesn't support this feature](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11461) out of the box last I checked. Other frameworks like `AngularJS` do support binary. Reference [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

`jquery-binary.js` is a *simple* `jQuery` Plugin I wrote for a couple of internal projects:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.downloadFile = function(url, data, requestType) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: requestType || 'POST',
            dataType: 'binary'
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var type = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            var filename = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            filename = filename && filename.indexOf('attachment') > -1
                ? filename.replace(/(?:[^=])+=/, '')
                : 'file.bin';
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
            saveAs(blob, filename);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        })
        ;
        return false;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

And the controller: **1.** parses the `HTML` string with `XMLWorkerHelper`; **2.** returns the PDF.

```
[HttpPost]  // some browsers have URL length limits
[ValidateInput(false)] // or throws HttpRequestValidationException
public ActionResult Index(string xHtml)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader(
        "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
    );
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xHtml))
    {
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
                document, Response.OutputStream
            );
            document.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                writer, document, stringReader
            );
        }
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Will let you decide how to deal with the inline styles. ;)

Comment: Cool deal. Thanks again @kuujinbo. I'll let you know how it turns out.