# using knockout to pass an HTML string to a C# controller. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, html, knockout.js, controller

Alright. I can *get* the HTML I need from the page (it's all in a DIV). That's not the problem. What I *need* to do is take the HTML and pass it, via a C# class into a controller.

I tried doing something like this with knockout/jQuery:

```
    var Details = $("#Details").html();
    console.log(Details);

    DetailsPdf.DetailsMarkup = JSON.stringify(Details);

    var jsonData = ko.toJS(Details);

    ko.utils.postJson("/MyController/MyAction", DetailsPdf);
```

The knockout actually DOES get me the relevant HTML. But when I pass it to my class, I get an exception that reads:

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client.

Then it ***partially*** shows the HTML I was sending as a part of the exception. I can't even seem to pass in the entities themselves without getting that exception.

This is an app with certain company-mandated security features, so turning off validation is not an option.

I need the HTML, or at least a way to re-create it on the server in the C#.

I'm still fairly new to knockout. Does anyone have any suggestions here?

Comment: Sounds like you're using anti forgery tokens. We need to see the relevant C# bits to be able to help. It would also help if you change your JS snippet to contain stubbed data instead of `$("#Details")`, because now we're missing part of that picture.

Comment: Essentially, I basically want to return an HTML table, and save it as a PDF. So I'd need to return the Table, TR, TD, and so forth.

Comment: Could be. But without the code / a repro, it's impossible for us to help you without resorting to guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have mentioned that:

> This is an app with certain company-mandated security features, so
>   turning off validation is not an option.

In your recent question [*Using iTextSharp with the knockout JavaScript framework?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342874). I could have provided *this* answer there.

I'm not sure why decorating the controllers Action with `[ValidateInput(false)]` isn't working, [but that answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342874/using-itextsharp-with-the-knockout-javascript-framework/35367792#35367792) fully working [source code is available](https://github.com/kuujinbo/StackOverflow.iTextSharp.MVC/blob/master/Controllers/KnockoutJS/DomToPdfController.cs). Whatever the reason, you should only need a few changes to workaround the issue:

**(1)** Base64 encode the HTML in your JavaScript:

```
ko.utils.postJson("/MyController/MyAction", window.btoa(DetailsPdf));
```

**(2)** Decode string in your MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string xHtml)
{
    xHtml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(xHtml));
```

**(3)** Deserialize that string to your model / entities with `Json.Net` or other.

Above steps **have also been** tested and verified working. ;)

Comment: Genius, @kuujinbo. That's just what I was looking for! Your answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to decorate your model (the one that the controller action is expecting) with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on the property that has the HTML.

When you do that, MVC skips the validation for that property.

[Here's a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to the documentation for more information.

**Note** Use this ONLY when you need to. It does open a vector for XSS if misused.

---

**Edit:** If for some reason, You can't use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute, you can turn off validating the request for that one action with `[ValidateInput(false)]`.

Same rules apply. Use that very sparingly. This means none of security validations will run against that particular model in that particular action only.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to add the AllowHtml (or, at least I can't find it on my machine). This particular app, I don't believe, is running on 4.0. They do keep a pretty tight leash on security here, I'll say that. I do have to wonder if it's possible for me to convert the string to a byte array, though there may be size limitations there.

Comment: @MJR I updated the answer to say you can also use `[ValidateInput(false)]`. However, AllowHtml has been in MVC for quite awhile (at least MVC3, probably earlier). You may be missing a reference?

Comment: I already tried the ValidateInput thing. The C# threw an exception before it even got to my controller. I'm probably just missing a reference somewhere for the AllowHtml.

Comment: @MJR Just to be safe, could you post the relevant parts of the controller (including any system using statements)?