# How can I use iText to convert HTML with images and hyperlinks to PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, xmlworker

I'm trying to convert `HTML` to `PDF` using iTextSharp in an `ASP.NET` web application that uses both [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), **and** [web forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms). The `<img>` and `<a>` elements have absolute and **relative** URLs, and some of the `<img>` elements are [**base64**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Typical answers here at SO and Google search results use generic `HTML` to `PDF` code with `XMLWorkerHelper` that looks something like this:

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xHtml))
{
    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
            writer, document, stringReader
        );
    }
}
```

So with sample `HTML` like this:

```
<div>
    <h3>HTML Works, but Broken in Converted PDF</h3>
    <div>Relative local <img>: <img src='./../content/images/kuujinbo_320-30.gif' /></div>
    <div>
        Base64 <img>:
        <img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' />
    </div>
    <div><a href='/somePage.html'>Relative local hyperlink, broken in PDF</a></div>
<div>
```

The resulting PDF: **(1)** is missing all images, and **(2)** all hyperlink(s) with relative URLs are broken and use a [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) (`file///XXX...`) instead of pointing to the correct web site.

Some answers here at SO and others from Google search recommend replacing relative URLs with absolute URLs, which is *perfectly acceptable* for one-off cases. However, globally replacing all `<img src>` and `<a href>` attributes with a hard-coded string is **unacceptable** for this question, so please do not post an answer like that, because it will accordingly be downvoted.

Am looking for a solution that works for **many** different web applications residing in test, development, and production environments.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see immediately that it indeed was your own question. Ok, next time I'll have a better look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Out of the box `XMLWorker` **[only understands absolute URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples_of_absolute_URIs)**, so the described issues are **expected** behavior. The parser can't automagically deduce [URI schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) or paths without some additional information.

Implementing an [ILinkProvider](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/pipeline/html/ILinkProvider.cs) fixes the broken hyperlink problem, and implementing an [IImageProvider](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/pipeline/html/IImageProvider.cs) fixes the broken image problem. Since both implementations must perform [URI resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#URI_resolution), that's the first step. The following helper class does that, and also tries to make web (`ASP.NET`) context calls (examples follow) as simple as possible:

```
// resolve URIs for LinkProvider & ImageProvider
public class UriHelper
{
    /* IsLocal; when running in web context:
     * [1] give LinkProvider http[s] scheme; see CreateBase(string baseUri)
     * [2] give ImageProvider relative path starting with '/' - see:
     *     Join(string relativeUri)
     */
    public bool IsLocal { get; set; }
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; private set; }
    public Uri BaseUri { get; private set; }

    public UriHelper(string baseUri) : this(baseUri, true) {}
    public UriHelper(string baseUri, bool isLocal)
    {
        IsLocal = isLocal;
        HttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        BaseUri = CreateBase(baseUri);
    }

    /* get URI for IImageProvider to instantiate iTextSharp.text.Image for 
     * each <img> element in the HTML.
     */
    public string Combine(string relativeUri)
    {
        /* when running in a web context, the HTML is coming from a MVC view 
         * or web form, so convert the incoming URI to a **local** path
         */
        if (HttpContext != null && !BaseUri.IsAbsoluteUri && IsLocal)
        {
            return HttpContext.Server.MapPath(
                // Combine() checks directory traversal exploits
                VirtualPathUtility.Combine(BaseUri.ToString(), relativeUri)
            );
        }
        return BaseUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFile 
            ? Path.Combine(BaseUri.LocalPath, relativeUri)
            // for this example we're assuming URI.Scheme is http[s]
            : new Uri(BaseUri, relativeUri).AbsoluteUri;
    }

    private Uri CreateBase(string baseUri)
    {
        if (HttpContext != null)
        {   // running on a web server; need to update original value  
            var req = HttpContext.Request;
            baseUri = IsLocal
                // IImageProvider; absolute virtual path (starts with '/')
                // used to convert to local file system path. see:
                // Combine(string relativeUri)
                ? req.ApplicationPath
                // ILinkProvider; absolute http[s] URI scheme
                : req.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
                    + HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath;
        }

        Uri uri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri)) return uri;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot create a valid BaseUri");
    }
}
```

Implementing `ILinkProvider` is pretty simple now that `UriHelper` gives the base URI. We just need the correct URI scheme (`file` or `http[s]`):

```
// make hyperlinks with relative URLs absolute
public class LinkProvider : ILinkProvider
{
    // rfc1738 - file URI scheme section 3.10
    public const char SEPARATOR = '/';
    public string BaseUrl { get; private set; }

    public LinkProvider(UriHelper uriHelper)
    {
        var uri = uriHelper.BaseUri;
        /* simplified implementation that only takes into account:
         * Uri.UriSchemeFile || Uri.UriSchemeHttp || Uri.UriSchemeHttps
         */
        BaseUrl = uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFile
            // need trailing separator or file paths break
            ? uri.AbsoluteUri.TrimEnd(SEPARATOR) + SEPARATOR
            // assumes Uri.UriSchemeHttp || Uri.UriSchemeHttps
            : BaseUrl = uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    public string GetLinkRoot()
    {
        return BaseUrl;
    }
}
```

`IImageProvider` only *requires* implementing a single method, `Retrieve(string src)`, but `Store(string src, Image img)` is easy - note inline comments there and for `GetImageRootPath()`:

```
// handle <img> elements in HTML  
public class ImageProvider : IImageProvider
{
    private UriHelper _uriHelper;
    // see Store(string src, Image img)
    private Dictionary<string, Image> _imageCache = 
        new Dictionary<string, Image>();

    public virtual float ScalePercent { get; set; }
    public virtual Regex Base64 { get; set; }

    public ImageProvider(UriHelper uriHelper) : this(uriHelper, 67f) { }
    //              hard-coded based on general past experience ^^^
    // but call the overload to supply your own
    public ImageProvider(UriHelper uriHelper, float scalePercent)
    {
        _uriHelper = uriHelper;
        ScalePercent = scalePercent;
        Base64 = new Regex( // rfc2045, section 6.8 (alphabet/padding)
            @"^data:image/[^;]+;base64,(?<data>[a-z0-9+/]+={0,2})$",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        );
    }

    public virtual Image ScaleImage(Image img)
    {
        img.ScalePercent(ScalePercent);
        return img;
    }

    public virtual Image Retrieve(string src)
    {
        if (_imageCache.ContainsKey(src)) return _imageCache[src];

        try
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(src, "^https?://", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return ScaleImage(Image.GetInstance(src));
            }

            Match match;
            if ((match = Base64.Match(src)).Length > 0)
            {
                return ScaleImage(Image.GetInstance(
                    Convert.FromBase64String(match.Groups["data"].Value)
                ));
            }

            var imgPath = _uriHelper.Combine(src);
            return ScaleImage(Image.GetInstance(imgPath));
        }
        // not implemented to keep the SO answer (relatively) short
        catch (BadElementException ex) { return null; }
        catch (IOException ex) { return null; }
        catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
    }

    /*
     * always called after Retrieve(string src):
     * [1] cache any duplicate <img> in the HTML source so the image bytes
     *     are only written to the PDF **once**, which reduces the 
     *     resulting file size.
     * [2] the cache can also **potentially** save network IO if you're
     *     running the parser in a loop, since Image.GetInstance() creates
     *     a WebRequest when an image resides on a remote server. couldn't
     *     find a CachePolicy in the source code
     */
    public virtual void Store(string src, Image img)
    {
        if (!_imageCache.ContainsKey(src)) _imageCache.Add(src, img);
    }

    /* XMLWorker documentation for ImageProvider recommends implementing
     * GetImageRootPath():
     * 
     * http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-10
     * 
     * but a quick run through the debugger never hits the breakpoint, so 
     * not sure if I'm missing something, or something has changed internally 
     * with XMLWorker....
     */
    public virtual string GetImageRootPath() { return null; }
    public virtual void Reset() { }
}
```

Based on the [XML Worker documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html) it's pretty straightforward to hook the implementations of `ILinkProvider` and `IImageProvider` above into  a simple parser class:

```
/* a simple parser that uses XMLWorker and XMLParser to handle converting 
 * (most) images and hyperlinks internally
 */
public class SimpleParser
{
    public virtual ILinkProvider LinkProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual IImageProvider ImageProvider { get; set; }

    public virtual HtmlPipelineContext HtmlPipelineContext { get; set; }
    public virtual ITagProcessorFactory TagProcessorFactory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICSSResolver CssResolver { get; set; }

    /* overloads simplfied to keep SO answer (relatively) short. if needed
     * set LinkProvider/ImageProvider after instantiating SimpleParser()
     * to override the defaults (e.g. ImageProvider.ScalePercent)
     */
    public SimpleParser() : this(null) { }
    public SimpleParser(string baseUri)
    {
        LinkProvider = new LinkProvider(new UriHelper(baseUri, false));
        ImageProvider = new ImageProvider(new UriHelper(baseUri, true));

        HtmlPipelineContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        // another story altogether, and not implemented for simplicity 
        TagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
        CssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
    }

    /*
     * when sending XHR via any of the popular JavaScript frameworks,
     * <img> tags are **NOT** always closed, which results in the 
     * infamous iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException:
     * 'Invalid nested tag a found, expected closing tag img.' a simple
     * workaround.
     */
    public virtual string SimpleAjaxImgFix(string xHtml)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(
            xHtml,
            "(?<image><img[^>]+)(?<=[^/])>",
            new MatchEvaluator(match => match.Groups["image"].Value + " />"),
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline
        );
    }

    public virtual void Parse(Stream stream, string xHtml)
    {
        xHtml = SimpleAjaxImgFix(xHtml);

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xHtml))
        {
            using (Document document = new Document())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                document.Open();

                HtmlPipelineContext
                    .SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory())
                    .SetLinkProvider(LinkProvider)
                    .SetImageProvider(ImageProvider)
                ;
                var pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
                var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(HtmlPipelineContext, pdfWriterPipeline);
                var cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(CssResolver, htmlPipeline);

                XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(worker);
                parser.Parse(stringReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As commented inline, `SimpleAjaxImgFix(string xHtml)` specifically handles [XHR that *may* send unclosed `<img>` tags](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20closing%20img%20tag), which is **valid** `HTML`, but **invalid** `XML` that **will** break `XMLWorker` . A simple explanation & implementation of how to receive a PDF or other binary data with XHR and iTextSharp [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342874#35367792).

A `Regex` was used in `SimpleAjaxImgFix(string xHtml)` so that anyone using (*copy/paste*?) the code doesn't need to add another `nuget` package, but a `HTML` parser like  [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) *should* be used, since it's turns this:

```
<div><img src='a.gif'><br><hr></div>
```

into this:

```
<div><img src='a.gif' /><br /><hr /></div>
```

with only a few lines of code:

```
var hDocument = new HtmlDocument()
{
    OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true,
    OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
};
hDocument.LoadHtml("<div><img src='a.gif'><br><hr></div>");
var closedTags  = hDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
```

Also of note - use `SimpleParser.Parse()` above as a *general* blueprint to additionally implement a custom [ICSSResolver](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/pipeline/css/ICSSResolver.cs) or [ITagProcessorFactory](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/html/ITagProcessorFactory.cs), which is [explained in the documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-8).

Now the issues described in the question should be taken care of. Called from a `MVC Action Method`:

```
[HttpPost]  // some browsers have URL length limits
[ValidateInput(false)] // or throws HttpRequestValidationException
public ActionResult Index(string xHtml)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader(
        "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
    );
    var simpleParser = new SimpleParser();
    simpleParser.Parse(Response.OutputStream, xHtml);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

or from a `Web Form` that gets `HTML` from a [server control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k26w4zzx.aspx):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        ConvertControlToPdf.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    }
    var simpleParser = new SimpleParser();
    simpleParser.Parse(Response.OutputStream, stringWriter.ToString());
}
Response.End();
```

or a simple HTML file with hyperlinks and images on the file system:

```
<h1>HTML Page 00 on Local File System</h1>
<div>
    <div>
        Relative &lt;img&gt;: <img src='Images/alt-gravatar.png' />
    </div>
    <div>
        Hyperlink to file system HTML page: 
        <a href='file-system-html-01.html'>Page 01</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

or HTML from a remote web site:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <img width="200" alt="Wikipedia Logo"
             src="portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png">
    </div>
    <div lang="en">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/">English</a>
    </div>
    <div lang="en">
        <a href="wiki/IText">iText</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above two `HTML` snippets run from a console app:

```
var filePaths = Path.Combine(basePath, "file-system-html-00.html");
var htmlFile = File.ReadAllText(filePaths);
var remoteUrl = Path.Combine(basePath, "wikipedia.html");
var htmlRemote = File.ReadAllText(remoteUrl);
var outputFile = Path.Combine(basePath, "filePaths.pdf");
var outputRemote = Path.Combine(basePath, "remoteUrl.pdf");

using (var stream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    var simpleParser = new SimpleParser(basePath);
    simpleParser.Parse(stream, htmlFile);
}
using (var stream = new FileStream(outputRemote, FileMode.Create))
{
    var simpleParser = new SimpleParser("https://wikipedia.org");
    simpleParser.Parse(stream, htmlRemote);
}
```

Quite a long answer, but taking a look at questions here at SO tagged [`html`, `pdf`, and `itextsharp`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=itextsharp+html+pdf), as of this writing (2016-02-23) there are *776 results* against 4,063 total tagged [`itextsharp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) - that's **19%**.

Comment: Not bad, such a long answer in such a short time... ;)

Comment: @mkl - Haha....been going back and forth about posting a question, then answering it myself for the past week or so. `<sarcasm>`Being the _eternal optimist_ `</sarcasm>` am hoping this helps a _tiny_ bit - even I'm getting tired of seeing versions 1.XX.XXX.XXXX spun off this or very similar concept. ;)

Comment: Nice @kuujinbo, this will be a great "close as duplicate" reference to have!

Comment: @ChrisHaas - thanks! :) Hope it helps clean things up here. (`itextsharp` tag)

Comment: This is great information and helped me understand [the iText documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-8). Seems logical that something like your SimpleParser would be part of iTextSharp. Any chance you'd consider submitting this as a [pull request](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/pulls)?

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful post,

I was problem to render images in my report html to pdf. with your post I could do it.

I'm working with asp.mvc 5.

I only have to change this method of the ImageProviderClass

```
public virtual string GetImageRootPath() { return null; }
```

to

```
public virtual string GetImageRootPath() { HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") }
```

thanks!