# iTextSharp HTML Parse "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: c#, itext, stringreader

I am having a bizarre issue trying to convert an HTML string to a PDF. I have tried several example for the internet and all are given me this same error on the htmlparser.Parse() method.

Here is the code:

```
Byte[] bytes;
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sbEmail.ToString());

var pdfDoc = new itxt.Document(itxt.PageSize.LETTER_LANDSCAPE, 15, 15, 0, 0);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();

    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();

    bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
}
```

There is no physical file path involved yet. So how can there be a problem with a file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this, can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181998/9492698

It's about HTMLWorker is deprecated and you can use XMLWorker instead.
See here for more advanced usage of XMLWorker: [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594030/how-can-i-use-itext-to-convert-html-with-images-and-hyperlinks-to-pdf)

Comment: XMLWorker is deprecated, you can use iText 7 + pdfHTML instead.